# Xcode copy resources to simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I want to copy files to the path that the Simulator will use. I'm talking about the path that looks something like this when the Simulator is running

`/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A9A30146-764F-4A4B-BAA2-00D5808D77C2/data/Containers/Data/Application/B85F7B67-FD50-48AA-8E03-2F806858AF71`

Is there a way to get that path at build time so that I can copy files there using a Run Script build phase?

---

### Here is why I want to do this:

Currently my app fetches a large amount of resources from the network every time the app is newly installed. The app checks the contents of the local file storage, and if a file is missing or out of date, it will sync them.

To speed up the development feedback cycle, I want to copy those resources from a local directory on my development machine, either during a build step or whenever else makes sense, to the proper destination in the simulator's local storage. This way, I can have a fast development cycle while only needing to delete the build script, or whatever other mechanism, when I'm ready to release the app into production.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy and paste below command to your `Run Script build phase`

```
cp -r "Your Resource Path" "`xcrun simctl get_app_container booted ${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}`"
```

`xcrun simctl get_app_container booted ${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}` -> This will take currently booted your product's path, you can even check from terminal like:
`xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.your.packagename`

Answer (score 0):

This is available to your Run Script build phase as the [`TARGET_BUILD_DIR`](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.3/#/itcaec37c2a6) environment variable. A reasonable place to copy these files to might be `$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH`. This is how CocoaPods installs resources from Pods, see https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/lib/cocoapods/generator/copy_resources_script.rb

However it's not clear why you would do this in a Run Script phase. For many uses you probably just want to use the existing Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

---

I don't think you have access to the path you are looking for at build time because the app is built prior to being installed and the installation path may not have even been determined when building the app.

To warm your cache or whatever you want to do for local development I see a few options:

1. Include these resources in your app bundle and then copy them to the appropriate destination directory at startup. This should be reliable and might be something you want to use in release builds if you want to include some default version of these resources in the app which can then be updated as needed when the app is launched. This approach also increases the size of your app bundle and if its not something you want in release builds might be more work to remove or disable in those environments.
2. Embed a reference to the location of your development files in the app at build time (e.g. a path relative to `SRCROOT`). Copy those files into place as needed when the app is launched. This would only work in the simulator and relies on the simulator not enforcing sandbox controls (allowing your app to read for a directory outside the simulator).
3. Download these files from a server as you would normally but host them locally so your development builds can fetch them from some `localhost` address quickly.

I'd try to use option 3 to mostly closely replicate the release behavior of the app but use whatever works best for your workflow.

Comment: I treid `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}` and it's value looks like `/Users/my_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CameraPermissionTest-dxeygpwfglbqmvbrykciwwuqyilr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos`. Does that eventually get copied to the simulator path, or how does this answer the question?

Comment: Also, how would I use the `Copy Bundle Resources` phase to move files or directories to the path in the original post?

Comment: Application resources are copied onto the target device as part of the application bundle when it is installed. They would then normally be relocated using `NSBundle`. Without an explanation of what you want to accomplish with these files it's hard to suggest a more specific answer.

Comment: i've edited the OP to explain what I'm trying to achieve.